# How do I adjust the speed of speech in Watson's Text to Speech service, via curl?

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson, ssml

*not experienced with coding, and such

I found the answer in break syntax of SSML, but am not sure if I can use that with the neural voices (V3) + not sure (if yes to the question here) on where i can insert those break syntax within my curl commands

Answer (score 0):

The cURL command for speech synthesis from the API docs is https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech#synthesize-audio-get

```
curl -X GET -u "apikey:{apikey}" --output hello_world.wav "{url}/v1/synthesize?accept=audio%2Fwav&amp;text=Hello%20world&amp;voice=en-US_AllisonV3Voice"
```

The text being processed is

```
text=Hello%20world
```

If you need to add in SSML Voice Transformation eg.

```xml
<voice-transformation rate="slow">
  Hello World
</voice-transformation>
```

Then you need to escape HTML characters to

```
text=&lt;voice-transformation rate=&quot;slow&quot;&gt;Hello%20world&lt;voice-transformation rate=&quot;slow&quot;&gt;
```

Making the full cURL

```
curl -X GET -u "apikey:{apikey}" --output hello_world.wav "{url}/v1/synthesize?accept=audio%2Fwav&amp;text=&lt;voice-transformation rate=&quot;slow&quot;&gt;Hello%20world&lt;voice-transformation rate=&quot;slow&quot;&gt;&amp;voice=en-US_AllisonV3Voice"
```

Currently only 3 voices can be modified like this - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/text-to-speech?topic=text-to-speech-transformation

- en-US_AllisonVoice
- en-US_LisaVoice
- en-US_MichaelVoice

So none of the neural voices.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the help. Want to mark your reply as answer - but just to clarify: do you happen to know how I can slow down the speech using punctuations perhaps? (I've tried period and commas). Thanks again.

Comment: You can add `<break>`, `<paragraph>`, or `<sentance>` - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/text-to-speech?topic=text-to-speech-timing

Comment: i understand this is using the websocket interface - do the 3 elements you suggested work with neural voices though? 
*pardon again, as not really a coder so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is not precise. You can control speaking rate for ALL IBM voices, just  use the prosody SSML markup:

```
<prosody rate="slow">Decrease speaking rate by 25%</prosody>
```