# Unable to apply any SSML tag to the text in IBM Watson's text-to-speech system, using CURL

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson, ssml

I'm successful in generating voices with Michael or Allison through CURL with IBM Watson, but as soon as I try to put any <> tag such as  or any <voice-transformation {attributes}> in the text, it fails, whether it's GET or POST. I found a few answers in here (including [How do I adjust the speed of speech in Watson's Text to Speech service, via curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322860/how-do-i-adjust-the-speed-of-speech-in-watsons-text-to-speech-service-via-curl)) but, anything I tried failed. For instance, I tried a break code this way:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{MYKEY}" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: audio/wav" --data "{\"text\":\"hello <break strength='500ms'></break> hello world\"}" --output hello_world.wav "https://api.us-east.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/{MYINSTANCE}/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_AllisonVoice"
```

Error i get is: "< was unexpected at this time."
Note that without the  code, it works well and text is generated.
and same for:

```
curl -X GET -u "apikey:{apikey}" --output hello_world.wav "{url}/v1/synthesize?accept=audio%2Fwav&amp;text=&lt;voice-transformation rate=&quot;slow&quot;&gt;Hello%20world&lt;voice-transformation rate=&quot;slow&quot;&gt;&amp;voice=en-US_AllisonV3Voice"
```

... as suggested by one answerer on the aforementioned page.

I also tried all sorts of attempts to urlencode the <> tags, to use different voice transformation tags, or none, or just break, I tried using single and double quotes, escaped or not, etc... it generally either returns

{
"error": "Bad request. (HAP)",
"code": 400,
"code_description": "Bad request"
}

or: "The system cannot find the file specified," or "< was unexpected at this time."

So I wish I could use all these SSML alterations, but so far, I've been unable to do it with curl. Let's hope someone knows how to do it.

P.S.: I tried it by pasting my full request in the command line in Windows and on a linux server using PuTTy.

Comment: How did you encode it? < and > are special characters in the Linux / UNIX shell

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the curl manual - https://curl.se/docs/manual.html

> The post data must be urlencoded. ... The data must be properly URL
> encoded. That means you replace space with + and that you replace
> weird letters with %XX where XX is the hexadecimal representation of
> the letter's ASCII code.

That mean you need to encode

`<` as  `%3C` although `&lt;` may also work

'>' as `%3E` although `&gt;` may also work

Comment: Thanks. This helped me make some progress. Once urlencoded, it does "work" in that it does not return an error, but the voice now reads out loud all the encoding: "hello plus percentage 3C" etc... he he.

Comment: Here is what I tried this time: curl -X POST -u "MYAPIKEY" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: audio/wav" --data "{\"text\":\"hello+%3Cbreak%3E%3C%2Fbreak%3E+world\"}" --output hello_world.wav "MYWATSONURL/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_AllisonVoice"

Comment: Did I misunderstand something in your explanation? Or do you have any other solution? I really wish I could apply those SSML effects.